# extend "declare type" with another "declare type"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm trying to create a type definition with optional object values. For example:

```
declare class SomeClass {
  street:string;
  name:string;
  whatever:number;
}
declare class Person {
  firstName:string;
  lastName:string;
  againWhatever:number;
}
declare class SomeClass extends SomeBase {
  //with the added irrelevant code this comment is needed
  //  person can either be a person OR UNDEFINED
  //  person is optional but declare class does not allow
  //  specifying optional members
  person? : Person
}

var s:SomeClass ={
  street:""
  ,name:""
  ,whatever:22
};
```

**[update]**
No compile error but Visual studio code put a red line under the `?` in the type definition. This must be a problem with 1.5.3, updating to 1.6.0 broke a lot so I got the "older" version, I'm using typescript 2.0.3 (node). Tried with 1.6.1 and that solved the problem for the typedef parsing (1.5.3) and imports breaking (1.6.0)

Sadly though; Visual Studio 2013 throws a build error: `A class member cannot be declared optional` preventing the project from being published.

Tried to get latest version of TypeScript for Visual Studio 2013 but it is the version I am already using. Checked the path environment variable and that is pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\`. Guess I have to wait for an update before I can continue working with these tools :-)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get compilation errors? What is `SomeBase`? What is `Person`? You haven't posted all of the relevant information.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thank you for the response. I'm sorry the question is unclear to you, not sure how else to explain it. I would like to know how do I specify a type with optional object members? person can be either a Person or undefined. Then how can I inherit from this type or how can this type inherit from anther type?

Comment: It's clear what you want. What's not clear is what problems are you facing? Your code compiles with no errors when I substitute the missing parts of your code my own. Maybe if you'll include in your code the parts of `SomeBase` and `Person` then the problem will be clear, but you haven't included them. So when I try it, it works fine. Can you please add the code for those and explain what is the problem you're having? Maybe an error message you are getting?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thank you again for your reply. I would like to provide a type definition of a model that is like another model (hence extend). The object members are optional so can either be of some type or undefined. I added person and SomeBase to the question but honestly do not see how that is going to help.

Comment: [Your code compiles just fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20class%20SomeBase%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20street%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20whatever%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20class%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20againWhatever%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20class%20SomeClass%20extends%20SomeBase%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20person%3F%3A%20Person%3B%0A%7D). There are no errors. I'm still trying to understand your problem

Comment: @NitzanTomer I'm trying this with visual studio code and it tells me in `declare class` I am not allowed to do `person?` (cannot put a question mark there). The `declare type` is wrong because `extends`. So I can either use `declare class` and not have optional members or use `declare type` and not extend from another type.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @NitzanTomer You are correct, sorry for waisting your time on this one and thank you for your patience. The typescript compiler has no problem with the definition. It is visual studio code (1.5.3) that complains about the definition file but then applies the definition correctly to code. Visual studio 2013 will error out as well `A class member cannot be declared optional` This will prevent the VS 2013 from publishing the project. So it is not TypeScript but the tools that are lacking.